# Using mixins to initialize class variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
    includes Skin
end
```

and the mixin module

```
module Skin
    def initialize
        self.skin = "fuzzy"
    end
end
```

I want it so that

```
>> Fruit.new
#<Fruit skin: "fuzzy", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ActiveRecord` `after_initialize` callback.

```
module Skin
  def self.included(base)
     base.after_initialize :skin_init
  end

  def skin_init
    self.skin = ...
  end
end

class Fruit < AR::Base
  include Skin
  ...
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Would it matter if Fruit was in a namespace? i.e. `Food::Fruit`

Comment: @Axsuul - see my edit. The `after_initialize` callback works a bit differently for Rails 3. Code updated now. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Sorry, forgot to mention I'm on Rails 3. Ah, so much hacking that Rails needs =/

Comment: Bonus Question: if I do Fruit.create(:skin => "smooth"), it does `#<Fruit skin: "fuzzy">`. How do I make it so that `create` override the mixin's value?

Comment: Change the code in the module to `self.skin ||= "fuzzy"`. That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the reader/writer for skin instead:

```
module Skin
  def skin
    @skin||="fuzzy"
  end
  attr_writer :skin
end

class Fruit
  include Skin
end

f=Fruit.new
puts f.skin # => fuzzy
f.skin="smooth"
puts f.skin # => smooth
```

Edit: for rails, you'd probably remove the `attr_writer` line and change `@skin` to `self.skin` or `self[:skin]`, but I haven't tested this. It does assume that you'll access skin first in order to set it, but you could get around this by coupling it with a default value in the database. There's probably a rails specific callback that will provide a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call super before you make any adjustments:

```
module Skin
  def initialize(*)
    super
    self.skin = "fuzzy"
  end
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Skin
end
```

Untested.

Comment: You shouldn't override `initialize` on `ActiveRecord` objects. Rails does not guarantee `initialize` is called in all situations. See here: http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I don't personally use ActiveRecord, but this is good to be aware of :)